# Javascript searchfunction

Tags: javascript, html, loops

I got a problem here. The search is working almost. But when I am deleting something it doesnt appear again. (tried something like `else {names[i].parentElement.style.display = "block"}`). This didnt work.
And maybe someone could tell me what to do if someone hits enter and everthing gets resetted. Thanks to every answer.

```js
function searchFunction() {
  const search = document.getElementById("myinput").value;
  const names = document.getElementsByClassName("names");
  console.log(search)
  for (var i = 0; i < names.length; i++) {
    if (names[i].innerHTML.toUpperCase().includes(search.toUpperCase()) == false) {
      names[i].parentElement.style.display = "none"
    }
  }

}
```

```html
<form class="search">
    <input class="bar" type="search" name="search" placeholder="Nach Mitarbeiter suchen" autocomplete="off" id="myinput" oninput="searchFunction()"> echo "
    <div class='gridRow'>
        <p class='rowElements names'>" . $user . "</p>

        <p class='rowElements beer'>" . $beer . "</p>

        <p class='invisibleBullshit'>" . $email . "</p>

        <input type='number' min='0' class='rowElements inputSize' placeholder='0' name='beerSub-"
                    . $user ."'>

        <button class='rowElements btn btn-primary btn-sm inputSize' onclick='payBeer(".' "'.$user.'" '.",".' "'.$email.'" '.")'>
            Bezahlen
        </button>
    </div>
</form>
```

Comment: Nothing reappears because you only hide stuff using `none` without ever resetting it. You likely need an `else names[i].parentElement.style.display = ""` part as well.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The easiest thing to do is switch between `block` and `none` based on whether the search term is found in the specified element.

Start typing "bob" or "john" in the example below to see the effect.

```js
function searchFunction() {
  const search = document.getElementById("myinput").value;
  const names = document.getElementsByClassName("names");
  //console.log(search)
  for (var i = 0; i < names.length; i++) {
     names[i].parentElement.style.display =  
        (names[i].innerHTML.toUpperCase().includes(search.toUpperCase()) 
            ? "block"
            : "none");
  }

}
```

```html
<form class="search">
     <input class="bar" type="search" name="search" placeholder="Nach Mitarbeiter suchen"autocomplete="off" id="myinput" oninput="searchFunction()">
     <div class='gridRow'>
         <p class='rowElements names'>Bob</p>
         <p class='rowElements beer'>Beer1</p>
         <p class='invisibleBullshit'>bob@bob.com</p>
         <input type='number' min='0' class='rowElements inputSize' placeholder='0' name='beerSub-bob'>
         <button class='rowElements btn btn-primary btn-sm inputSize' onclick='payBeer("bob","bob@bob.com")'>
             Bezahlen
          </button>
     </div>
     <div class='gridRow'>
         <p class='rowElements names'>John</p>
         <p class='rowElements beer'>Beer2</p>
         <p class='invisibleBullshit'>john@john.com</p>
         <input type='number' min='0' class='rowElements inputSize' placeholder='0' name='beerSub-john'>
         <button class='rowElements btn btn-primary btn-sm inputSize' onclick='payBeer("john","john@john.com")'>
             Bezahlen
          </button>
     </div>
</form>
```

Comment: Thank thought is was wrong when i tried it because I got a grid for the rows. And i needed to set in to display "flex" or "none". But thanks for your help.

Comment: Setting back the display to an empty string is usually better. Like this you overwrite any css definition the user could have set somewhere.

Comment: @Lain I totally get (and agree with) your point, but setting it back to blank would _also_ overwrite anything that came before. In fact the only safe thing to do is reset it back to _whatever it was before you changed it_. That's an exercise for future readers and this OP.

Comment: It would not overwrite css definitions atleast, merely inline styles.